# Why do I get the following error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"? - and how can I fix it specifically?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, error-handling, fatal-error

This is my code:

```
var usernames = [""]
var userids = [""]
var isFollowing = ["":false]

var refresher: UIRefreshControl!

func refresh() {

    var query = PFUser.query()

    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let users = objects {

            self.usernames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.userids.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            self.isFollowing.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

            for object in users {

                if let user = object as? PFUser {

                    if user.objectId != PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId {

                        self.usernames.append(user.username!)
                        self.userids.append(user.objectId!)

                        var query = PFQuery(className: "followers")

                        query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
                        query.whereKey("following", equalTo: user.objectId!)

                        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

                            if let objects = objects {

                                if objects.count > 0 {

                                    self.isFollowing[user.objectId!] = true

                                } else {

                                    self.isFollowing[user.objectId!] = false

                                }
                            }

                            if self.isFollowing.count == self.usernames.count {

                                self.tableView.reloadData()

                                self.refresher.endRefreshing()

                            }

                        })


                    }

                }

            }

        }





    })
```

I get the fatal error on this lines which says:

> query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
>                               query.whereKey("following", equalTo: user.objectId!)

How can I fix this? I have searched several other posts and have been unable to find something useful. Please be very specific when you do give advice--I'm relatively a newbie.

Comment: your `PFUser.currentUser() == nil` or `PFUser().currentUser?.objectId == nil` or `user.objectId == nil` Check to see which one is null

Comment: How would I go about checking that, @milo526? I'm so bad, sorry.

Comment: Use a breakpoint, or log the values to the console.

Comment: nilPFUser.currentUser()!.objectId is nil
What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, one of your values is nil.

Insert following code before your queries and fix the method which returns nil :

```
if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {
    print("currentUser() is nil");
} else if (PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId == nil) {
    print("PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId is nil");
} else if (user.objectId == nil) {
    print("user.objectId is nil");
}
```

Comment: This was printed in the logs: nilPFUser.currentUser()!.objectId is nil.
What should I do now? I really suck, sorry.

Comment: thank you, but I don't know specifically what to do next

Comment: Seems that PFUser.currentUser() returns you a valid user object, with it's objects ID set to nil. How are you initialising your userObject? You should set it before using it.

Answer (score 0):

There was for sure a problem with the Parse log in.
Are you calling the log in function before during the query in your program? 
And are you checking the result variables?